# Unable to install react-native app into mobile( Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden)

Tags: android, gradle, react-native, proxy, build.gradle

I am having trouble setting up react-native Android project.I was behind a proxy that just didn't allow the repository site.So i configured proxy settings in gradle.properties file like below.If i don't configured the above properties gradle is not downloading.

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxy ip
systemProp.http.proxyPort=port
systemProp.http.proxyUser=my user name
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=my password
```

Now I am getting the following error message:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'pmdemo'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1.
 Required by:
     :pmdemo:unspecified
  > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1.
     > Could not get resource 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/
       build/gradle/1.3.1/gradle-1.3.1.pom'.
        > Could not GET 'http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/
  gradle/1.3.1/gradle-1.3.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: 
  Forbidden
```

Can any one help me to come out of this.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I fix this issue. Just change protocol on your build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com"} // http -> https
    }
    dependencies {
       ...
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url "https://jcenter.bintray.com"} // http -> https
    }
}
```